# setTimeout for a function that checks the keys that are pressed (javascript)

Tags: javascript, events, timeout

I want to register key presses with javascript, but not until a certain time has passed. Ultimately, I want to make a video stop playing with this, log key values and the timestamp, however to make the code more simple, I did not include this functionality here.

I tried implementing the function checkKeyPress into the function setTimeout, which does not work, and I cannot figure out, why, since both functions work on their own. With the code below, however, the code logs "undefined" instead of the value of the key that was pressed.

```
// set the time offset to be 5000 ms
   var timePress = 5000;

   window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress, false); //call checkKeyPress upon key press
   var keynum; // initialize the variable 'keynum'


   function checkKeyPress(e) {  //define the function checkKeyPress
       if(window.event) {  // in Internet Explorer, different browsers may need different event calls              
         keynum = e.keyCode;
       } else if(this.which){  // in Netscape/Firefox/Opera                   
         keynum = e.which;
       }

       // just for checking, log the value of keynum
       console.log(keynum)

       // if the keys 0 or 1 are pressed
       if (keynum == '48' || keynum == '49'){ 
         alert(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
       }
   }

   setTimeout(checkKeyPress('keydown'), timePress);
```

Comment: First the setTimeout call is wrong. It is executing the function and returning what it returns to the setTimeout. Second, makes not sense to call that function. The code is expecting an event, and you are passing it a string.

Comment: Can't you just put the `addEventListener` inside the `setTimeout`? Basically, don't bind the event listener until you actually want it?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. Do you want to wait some time before you start listening for key events?  Or listen for key events from the beginning, but only respond after some time has passed?  Or something else?  What you're code is trying to do is call the keydown handler manually at some interval, which isn't sensible - a keydown handler should be called by the system in response to an event

Comment: (also @Niet the Dark Absol) To clarify what I am trying to do: I want to get the keypress from the beginning, but only allow the user to elicit the event (stop the video) once a certain time has passed. Therefore, including the addEventListener inside the setTimeout does not help me to the full extent (also I did not get this to work). However, I guess, I could create two different EventListeners, one for getting key presses before, and one for getting key presses after the timePress time has passed. I am new to javascript, therefore am not sure, if this is an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The final line should probably be

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    checkKeyPress('keydown'); 
}, timePress);
```

note that I'm not invoking checkKeyPress, im using an anonymous function which does so.

Note, the ES6 version would be

```
setTimeout( ()=> { 
    checkKeyPress('keydown'); 
}, timePress);
```